# When making binary masks for working and isolating bits and bytes, what's the fastest way to convert from Binary to Hex?

Tags: c, binary, bitmask

Assume I have the following binary string:

```
110110010110
```

From which I need only the 4th 5th and 6th bits, we've learned to use a mask like this

```
000000111000
```

So with the binary `&` operation I will get the bits I wanted and all I have left to do is shift them to the right.

Since C does not work with plain binary numbers we were told it's easiest to convert the binary mask string to a hexadecimal number. My lecturer used a super quick method to convert a binary string to a hexadecimal number.

What is the easiest and correct way to create those masks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each set of four bits corresponds to one hex 'digit'. Learn those, then just start converting blocks of four from right to left. (If you're converting a bit string that's not a multiple of four bits, then just add zeros to the left end until it is for the last conversion.)

0000 : 0x0
0001 : 0x1
0010 : 0x2
0011 : 0x3
0100 : 0x4
0101 : 0x5
0110 : 0x6
0111 : 0x7
1000 : 0x8
1001 : 0x9
1010 : 0xA
1011 : 0xB
1100 : 0xC
1101 : 0xD
1110 : 0xE
1111 : 0xF

Comment: The list you've provided is actually all I have to know?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. Since 16 is a power of 2, there's this direct correspondence, unlike with decimal.

Comment: So my lecturer didn't use any trick actually, he just knows this 'conversion table' by heart...?

Comment: You don’t even need to know it “by heart”; you just need to know how to read four-digit binary numbers.  For your example: `b0000 0011 1000` —> `0x038`.

Comment: @Quaker: you don't even need to know it by heart, just do a bin=>hex conversion 4 bits at time (1011 => 1+2+8=11=0xB).

Comment: @StephenCanon: now I'm scared. :-/

Comment: The LSB contributes 1, the one to its left contributes 2 the one to its left 4 and the MSB contributes 8? so I just sum up considering if the bit is 'on' or 'off'?

Comment: @Quaker: of course, but this is *really* basic binary arithmetic, if you have doubts about this you should revise a bit the topic.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I will, I've learned it in the introduction to computer science course a year ago, three semesters ago. enough time to forget :-)

Comment: Yes, you do learn it "by heart" if you don't want to consult a table every time you convert.  The addition "table" for base ten has 45 different facts, plus the "catchall" facts that n+0=n and a+b=b+a.  If kids can do that, surely an adult can do 15 more.

Comment: @Quaker: practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 1):

For string to string?  Grab 4 bits, find the number (0-15) then use as index for a table lookup.  For a mask:

```
hex_digit = val & 0x0F;
```

Shift down 4 bits with:

```
val = val >> 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it would be helpful to cut your big string into smaller pieces of four bits, starting from the end (least significant bit). For example, your binary number `110110010110` could be written as `1101 1001 0110`. If you have a number that can't be properly cut into pieces of four bits, say `1000011010`, you should write it as `10 0001 1010`.

Now, it's much more simple. In hexadecimal notation, `0` is 0 and `f` is 15. You start counting from zero, but instead of using 10 symbols, you now use 16. So it goes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f.

You can replace each group of bits with its hexadecimal symbol! In your example (i.e. `1101 1001 0110`) it would be `d96`, while in my example (i.e. `10 0001 1010`) it would be `21a`. For every one you find in a binary string, you add `2 ^ (position - 1)` to your result, where `position = 1` for the least significant bit. For example in `0110` you have 1 in position 2 (i.e. `2 ^ (2 - 1) = 2 ^ 1 = 2`) and in position 3 (i.e. `2 ^ (3 - 1) = 2 ^ 2 = 4`), so it is `2 + 4 = 6`. Now, simply prepend `0x` to tell the compiler that what follows is a Hexadecimal number and it becomes `0xd96`.

In any case, writing a number as it is means it is in decimal notation, prepending a `0` suggests it is octal and prepending a `0x` suggests it is a hexadecimal.

I hope this helps! :D